# how to extract partail value of elements and display them in bold/italic/list while converting an xml to html output in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am working on XML transformations.I have to exctrat velue of an element and display them in bold/italic/list.
Source:

```
 <content>
    <bodyParagraphText>
ABCD<strong   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">:<dynamicVariable  name='BOLD'></dynamicVariable></strong>
 </bodyParagraphText>  
 </content>
```

1.Output required1(bold):

```
<aaa>
     ABCD **BOLD**
</aaa>
```

2.Output required1(list):

```
<aaa>
     ABCD 

 - BOLD

</aaa>
```

3.Output required1(underline):

```
  <aaa>
     ABCD BOLD(underlined)
  </aaa>
```

I am completely new to it. I am not getting any ideas to work on.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Those output samples - is that literally what you're supposed to output? Or are you supposed to output HTML with bold/list/underline (or italic) formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat guessing about what it is you need to do, but:

- On your `xsl:stylesheet` element, declare a namespace prefix for xhtml, such as `"xhtml"`.
- Create a template that matches `"content/bodyParagraphText"`.
- Use XPath expression `"text()[1]"` to get the 'ABCD' text, apparently. Put this in a variable, such as `abcd`.
- Use XPath expression `".//xhtml:dynamicVariable/@name"` to get 'BOLD'. Put this in a variable, such as `dv`.
- To specify your output, use something like

:

```
<aaa>
  <xsl:value-of select="$abcd" /> **<xsl:value-of select="$dv" />**
</aaa>
```

for the first output format required.

If I have misunderstood your question, please clarify...

Comment: @LarsH..Thank you for your response. The output samples convey the literal meaning only. Can you provide me the comple XSLT.

Comment: @muzimil, I'm a bit wary of providing a full implementation "for you", without any evidence that you're trying something. For one thing, I don't know if this is an assignment for school. I would suggest that you read an introduction or tutorial on XSLT, make an attempt at solving the problem, then come back and show us your attempt, and ask questions about how to improve it. Giving you a solution without your learning anything would be pointless. Teaching you XSLT from scratch would be too difficult for a StackOverflow answer.